# Assigning the result of the query variable to another query variable in CSWP

Tags: search, user-profile, query, managed-property, cswp

I am using content search webpart. I have the query that fetches all the items from a list like

`(HRDepartmentOWSTEXT:"a*" OR HRDepartmentOWSTEXT:"b*" OR HRDepartmentOWSTEXT:"c*"...so on)`.

Here "HRDepartmentOWSTEXT" is a managed column.This works fine.

I need to assign these values from the list to the "Department" of user.I should be something like

```
Department=(All the values of the managed column "HRDepartmentOWSTEXT")
```

I tried this,
`Department={((HRDepartmentOWSTEXT:"a*" OR HRDepartmentOWSTEXT:"b*" OR HRDepartmentOWSTEXT:"c*"...so on)}`

But I couldn't retrieve any result.Can anyone suggest how to apply this query.

*Note:I have added query rule to local SharePoint result source to include people search.*